# Clear FacesMessage on clicking FileUpload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page to upload a file. If there is a message on the page previously due to success/failure of some operation, I want it to go away as soon as I click the button to Upload a file. But I saw that update only works after the file upload completes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PF8+ since you did not mention your version you can remove it with Jquery on Adding of file...

```xml
<p:fileUpload onAdd="$('.ui-messages').css('display','none');" ...
```

The above is shortened for brevity but basically hides the messages when you add a file.

Comment: I am using PF 5.1.  I  may have some error messages due to previous operations which I want to go away when I click on the button to upload the file. It does not go away at that time. It only goes away after the file upload is completed. The above did not work.

Comment: Yeah I have to look at the docs.  5.1 is VERY old and `onAdd` might not be available.   In your app just press F12 to open develop console and type `$('.ui-messages').css('display','none');` does that make your messages go away at least?

Comment: Yes, this works. I also added it to "onStart". It makes the message go away but only after I select the file. Without it, the messages would only go away after the file was uploaded and the method returned. I am still working on removing the messages as soon as the user clicks on the "Upload File" button

Comment: I actually called a <p:remoteCommand for onstart: . This calls a message in teh bean, where I need to clear some error Lists too. The update: for this remote command updates teh messages thus removing those messages. The only thing is, it happens once I choose the file to upload. I was hoping to clear all this messages before I get the window to choose the file.

Comment: Why not use Jquery to subscribe to onClick of the Upload button and call your remoteCommand?  Example: `$('.ui-fileupload-upload').on('click', function() {alert('I was clicked')});`